# Backbone.js equivalent of django humanize - int.word and int.comma - using underscore.string

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is it possible to perform the equivalent of an `int.word|int.comma` with underscore.string? I would like to do this to the following cell.

```
<td class="nowValue"><%= careerStrikes %>/<%= avgStrikesPG %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `Backbone` or `Underscore` provide a humanize like set of methods. You would need to write this yourself or use one of the many libraries available to do this. One example being [here](https://github.com/taijinlee/humanize).